# reading a big bin-file(~2mb) in c

Tags: c, file, bin

I want to read a bin-file with a size under 2mb.

At the moment my code for reading the bin file looks like this:

edit:

```
#define MAX_BYTES_IN_FILE 500000         // ~ 2mb
#define ERROR_FILE 1

int get_byte_from_file(FILE *stream, unsigned char *dataarray) {
    int counter = 0;
                               
    while ((dataarray[counter] = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
        counter += 1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Main looks like this for the example use of the function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *datei;
   
    unsigned int number_of_bytes;
    unsigned char *dataarray;

    dataarray = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * MAX_BYTES_IN_FILE);

    datei = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   
    number_of_bytes = get_byte_from_file(datei, dataarray);
   
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_bytes; i++)
        printf("%x ", dataarray[i]);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I did a simple mistake but cant see it the error is still: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: This array might be to large to be allocated on stack. Not sure what you need it for at all

Comment: Hmmm. That array is completely useless. You only use it to read a single character and assign it to `dataarray[counter]` immediately. Why not replace it with a single `char` instead? Or use `dataarray` as buffer for reading data (not 1 byte at a time, but bigger chunks) directly into that buffer

Comment: On Microsoft Windows, the default stack size is 1 MB. On Linux, the default stack size is (I believe) 8 MB. However, these values can be configured. Therefore, your program is likely crashing due to a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), because local variables/arrays are stored on the stack. For this reason, I suggest you use dynamic memory allocation instead, for example the function [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Comment: There mighe be another reason for segmenataion fault. How do you know how big the buffer is where `dataarray` is pointint to? Besides crashing your stack you might as well writing out of bounds while copying the character to that buffer.

Comment: besides, what do you pass as `dataarray`?

Comment: Please do not modify your question in a way that makes comments (or answers) useless. Instead only add new information. No one wants to aim at a moving target and waste their time.

Comment: Your changed code is also wrong: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not an `unsigned char`. How would `unsigned char` ever be able to hold `EOF`?

Comment: Your code is not ensuring that `argc >= 2`. If `argc == 1`, then `argv[1] == NULL`, which will likely cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
void *readfile(FILE *fi, long *filesize)
{
    void *buff;
    fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_END);
    *filesize = ftell(fi);
    fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buff = malloc(*filesize);
    if(buff)
    {
        fread(buff, 1, *filesize, fi);
    }
    return buff;
}
```

You need to add error checks- I did not as it is only the idea.

And your usage:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 
   FILE *datei;
   
   long number_of_bytes;
   unsigned char *dataarray;

   datei=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
   
   dataarray = readfile(datei, &number_of_bytes);
   
   for (int i=0;dataarray && i<number_of_bytes;i++)
       printf("%hhx ",dataarray[i]);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not helpful when you only present working code as an answer, and never explain what the OP did wrong. That way they cannot learn, they only become Voodoo-Coders who depend on StackOverflow to fix their codes.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Not only that, the code isn't necessarily going to work.  It has absolutely no error checking, and using `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file on a stream can fail in so many ways - reading from a pipe, `fseek()` to the end of a binary stream on some systems doesn't work, on Windows where `long` is only 32 bits if will fail for files 2GB or larger, etc.

Comment: `long` is maybe not large enough to hold the size of a file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle OP is reading file ~2MB. Long will be enough. For the OPs purpose fseek/ftell is good enough

Comment: @P__J__ *For the OPs purpose fseek/ftell is good enough*  Until the time it's not.  Buggy code is buggy code even if the bug isn't triggered.

Answer (score 3):

This line is sufficient to crash your program:

```
while ((dataarray[counter] = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
```

Let's go through it step by step:

1. `fgetc(stream)` reads a byte and returns its value or `EOF`. Because a byte can have any possible value, `fgetc()` returns a larger `int`, which can hold an `EOF` value that is distinct from any byte value that might be found in the file.
2. You assign this `int` value to an `unsigned char`. An `EOF` value will be truncated to this datatype.
3. The value of the assignment is of type `unsigned char`, and the converted `EOF` value is not equal to `EOF` anymore. Thus, the comparison always fails, and your program keeps fetching data until the buffer overruns and nasty things begin to happen.

You need to store the result of `fgetc()` in an `int` variable until you've checked that it is indeed not the `EOF` value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a segmentation fault is your allocation is incorrect: you allocate `MAX_BYTES_IN_FILE` bytes instead of `unsigned int` elements. As allocated, the array has only `MAX_BYTES_IN_FILE / sizeof(unsigned int)` elements, whereas the file is probably `MAX_BYTES_IN_FILE * sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes long.

You are reading bytes from the file (values between `0` and `255`) but you use `unsigned int` elements. What is the logic? Does the file contain 32-bit values or individual bytes?

Once you can confirm that the file contents is exactly the same as the representation of the array in memory, you can use `fread()` to read the whole file in a single call.